# Making sure of sending commands to firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How can I be sure that this sequence of commands to firestore will be done completely?

```
FirebaseFirestore.instance
          .collection('Example')
          .doc(Example.id)
          .collection("Example")
          .doc(Example.iD)
          .delete()
          .then((_) => FirebaseFirestore.instance
              .collection('Example')
              .doc(Example.iD)
              .collection("Example")
              .doc(Example)
              .delete())
          .then((_) => FirebaseFirestore.instance
                  .collection("Example")
                  .doc(Example.id)
                  .delete()
                  .then((_) {
                _privateChatInfoList.removeWhere((key, value) => key == id);
                notifyListeners();
              }));
```

To be more clear : how I can be sure that if any problem, error or bug happen will not cause an interruption between commands to just send the first or the second one only!

Comment: Not sure if I understand you correctly, but if you're asking how to transactionally manipulate data, I'd recommend using a transaction: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're asking how to transactionally manipulate data, I'd recommend [using a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions). If you don't need any existing data from the documents, you can also [use a batched write](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions#batched-writes) operation, which is a bit simpler.